# Two-field comparator CLIPS

Tags: clips

I need to write a comparator to order facts in CLIPS. This comparator must sort the facts according to a first field (sum-certanties) and if the first field were not enough to find a sort, I would like it to order them according to the second field (total-price).

This is what I wrote, but it doesn't work ...

```
(deffunction MAIN::rating-sort (?f1 ?f2)
   (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return TRUE
   else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return FALSE
        else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return TRUE
             else (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return FALSE
                  else then return FALSE)))))
```

Descending order for sum-certainties and ascending order for total-price.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a set of facts CLIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026686/sort-a-set-of-facts-clips)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine. You just need to pass its name and a list of facts into the sort function.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction MAIN::rating-sort (?f1 ?f2)
   (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return TRUE
   else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 sum-certainties) (fact-slot-value ?f2 sum-certainties)) then return FALSE
        else (if (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return TRUE
             else (if (< (fact-slot-value ?f1 total-price) (fact-slot-value ?f2 total-price)) then return FALSE
                  else then return FALSE)))))
CLIPS>                   
(deftemplate thing
   (slot sum-certainties)
   (slot total-price))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts things
   (thing (sum-certainties 90) (total-price 200))
   (thing (sum-certainties 30) (total-price 100))
   (thing (sum-certainties 30) (total-price 300))
   (thing (sum-certainties 90) (total-price 150))
   (thing (sum-certainties 50) (total-price 150))
   (thing (sum-certainties 70) (total-price 200)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS>    
(foreach ?f (sort rating-sort (find-all-facts ((?f thing)) TRUE))
   (printout t (fact-slot-value ?f sum-certainties) " " (fact-slot-value ?f total-price) crlf))
90 150
90 200
70 200
50 150
30 100
30 300
CLIPS>
```